# ORA-00942 error when running code to create trigger that inserts rows from data dictionary views

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert, ddl, database-trigger

I am building a table that takes in table/view name, created date and the name of the creator as soon as a table is built. I have written a trigger to do the same which uses the insert statement and takes the required data from user_objects, user_tables and v$session. However, when I run the trigger, I get the "PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CREATE_TRIGGER
AFTER CREATE ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO NEW_OBJ_TRACKER (TBL_OR_VW_NAME, CREATED_DATE_TIME, LAST_QUERIED_DATE, CREATOR)
SELECT T4.* , T5.* FROM
 (
 SELECT OBJECT_NAME, CREATED, LAST_ANALYZED
 FROM SYS.USER_OBJECTS T1 LEFT JOIN SYS.USER_TABLES T2
 ON T1.OBJECT_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME
 ORDER BY CREATED DESC
 ) T4,
 (
 SELECT OSUSER
 FROM SYS.v$session
 ORDER BY SQL_EXEC_START
 ) T5
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1
 ;
 END;
/
```

When I run just the the insert statement, I get no error and the results are fine.

Comment: If memory serves, the data dictionary tables won't have the information for the newest table if you query them inside the trigger.  I would also not expect that looking for the session with the most recent `sql_exec_start` would give you the user that created the table unless you happen to be on a very lightly used system.

Comment: I'm all ears if you have better ideas. Basically the situation here is that there is only one login to this schema and it had led to a proliferation of tables and views under this schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger is querying `sys.v$session`. Privileges on the v$ tables are granted via a role and are not usable from procedures, functions, or triggers.

In order for your trigger to be able to query the v$ table, you need to grant it directly to the owner of the trigger, e.g. (run this as SYS):

```
grant select on v_$session to [user];
```

(replace [user] with the owner of your trigger).

Comment: Should this line of code be placed inside the trigger?

Comment: No, you run this once as SYS.